# Jupyter Notebook runs import statements, then hangs

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, python-import, jupyter

My Jupyter Notebook will no long "Run All Above". It runs the first cell (import statements), seemingly without an error, then won't run anything after that, even when they are simple function definitions. If I reverse the order, it will run everything up to and including the import statements, but nothing after. If I run the cells one-by-one, they work fine, so that leads me to believe I have some problem with the way Jupyter is handling one or more of my imports. I also cannot interrupt the kernel; the un-run cells still show as busy. I have to restart the kernel to run it again.

Here is the About information from Jupyter:

```
The version of the notebook server is 4.1.0 and is running on:
Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec 19 2016, 13:29:36) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

Current Kernel Information:

Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:17:26) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 4.0.3 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
%guiref   -> A brief reference about the graphical user interface.
```

Here are my import statements:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
import datetime
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
import pdfkit

# %matplotlib inline
```

And a generic function that doesn't run if I run the imports first, but will run if I run it before the imports.

```
def load_data(file_path):
    """Function that does something"""
    pass
```

I've tried commenting out the imports one-by-one but nothing changed. It also runs fine on my MacBook. Any ideas?

Comment: UPDATE: I found [this thread](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/5629), though I still encounter the problem even when I remove the `%matplotlib inline` from my code.

Comment: UPDATE (again): if I keep the `%matplotlib inline` in the code (i.e., not commented out), things run fine. I have no idea why, but that solved the problem.

Comment: Just encountered this problem yesterday and today. Who knows...

Comment: *And did not find a solution.

Comment: @Evan I was heartened to know that none of the IPython devs could figure it out either. https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/5629